# Android O | API Level 26 or 27

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo

I am moving on Android O and below is my configuration:

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion 26.0.0
targetSdkVersion 26
com.android.support:appcompat-v7: 27.1.1
com.android.support:support-v4: 27.1.1
com.android.support:recyclerview-v7: 27.1.1
com.android.support:design: 27.1.1
com.android.support:support-annotations: 27.1.1
```

**Q1** As per Android guideline:

> In the second half of 2018, Play will require that new apps and app updates target a recent Android API level.

The recent Android API version is 27 (8.1) but In my case, compileSdkVersion 26, buildToolsVersion 26.0.0,  targetSdkVersion 26. So as per guideline, should I keep 26 or 27?

**Q2** What if I keep using compileSdkVersion 26, buildToolsVersion 26.0.0,  targetSdkVersion 26 ? Is this violation of guideline or it's fine?

**Q3** Is it fine if I keep support library version as 27.1.1 and compileSdkVersion 26, buildToolsVersion 26.0.0,  targetSdkVersion 26? Is there something wrong with this combination?

Answer (score 1):

> below is my configuration:

You should be getting complaints in Android Studio about having a `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersion` that are lower than the major version of the support libraries that you are trying to use.

> So as per guideline, should I keep 26 or 27?

We have no way of knowing for certain what Google will require. I recommend moving your `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 27.

> Is it fine if I keep support library version as 27.1.1 and compileSdkVersion 26, buildToolsVersion 26.0.0, targetSdkVersion 26? Is there something wrong with this combination?

There is rarely a reason to keep your `buildToolsVersion` artificially low. And, as noted above, you should get complaints (and possibly build errors) given your combination of values. I recommend moving your `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 27, and set your `buildToolsVersion` to the latest (`27.0.3` IIRC).